# How do I autowire Spring config in a Executable Jar using Scala?

Tags: spring, scala

I have a simple Scala executable jar, and I am trying to use Spring Dependency injection to grab configuration information.

I start with the main class like this...

```
object Main{
  def main ( args: Array[String] ) :Unit = {
    ...
  };
}
```

This seems to work fine with no config so I try adding the config. I have a simple application.yml like this

```
application
  username: ${MY_ENV_VAR}
  password: ${MY_OTHER_ENV_VAR}
```

I try to implement this like the following....

```
@Configuration
class ExportConfig {
  @Value("${application.username}")
  var username: String = _
  @Value("${application.password}")
  var password: String = _
}

@Component
class Export(){
  @Autowired
  var config: ExportConfig = _
  def doSomething(...): String = {
    val obj = new DoSomethingElse(
      config.username,
      config.password
    )
    ...
  }
}
```

And then change the original main to look like this...

```
object Main{
  def main ( args: Array[String] ) :Unit = {
    val export: Export = new Export();
    export.doSomething();
    ...
  };
}
```

But config is always null. What am I missing? How do I autowire using an executable Jar?

Comment: how are you component-scanning? or maybe the problem is you aren't?

Comment: Good question, I was looking for a technical term for this and that sounds correct. How would I component scan as an executable JAR? I found this and was going to try that (https://better-coding.com/spring-how-to-autowire-bean-in-a-static-class/) but I haven't had luck yet

Comment: if you look at a normal spring boot java application it has component scanning on the main class using an annotation called SpringBootApplication which implements ComponentScan.  what that link says sounds horrible. alternatively try using partial application where spring uses DI. if all you need is DI then maybe you can get by wihout spring.

Comment: Sometimes all you need are the right Google terms :-). You helped me a bunch thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

```
// src/main/resources/application-context.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.where.export.is" />

</beans>

// Main 
def main ( args: Array[String] ) :Unit = {
    val ctx:ApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

    val exporter = ctx.getBean(classOf[Export])
    ...
}
```

Now it is getting all the properties I would expect.